# Backspace key is reverted in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, backspace, eclipse-mars

My backspace key in Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) works like the delete key: it deletes the right character instead of the left one. That's really confusing

Maybe I accidentally used a shortcut key?

I tried to restart Eclipse but it didn't work. I also tried to switch the key binding preferences to "Emacs" scheme before reverting to "Default" but that didn't work either.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Edit: damn, I just found out that ctrl+x doesn't work any more either!

Comment: I also have the same issue. but mines ctrl+x is working.

Comment: I would believe this is the same problem as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824076/ubuntu-eclipse-backspace-key-started-working-like-delete-key). (Also has a workaround)

Comment: Thank you Javich. It indeed seems to be the same problem. However, I tried the workaround but it doesn't work.

Comment: I got solved. try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824076/ubuntu-eclipse-backspace-key-started-working-like-delete-key/33866557#33866557

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got solved:

Go to "Window -> Preferences". Then inside the tree navigate to "General -> Keys".

In the right side of the window, type "Delete" where it says "type filter text".

Find the COMMAND: Delete, BINDING: Backspace and click on UnBind Command button at the bottom. Click Apply, then OK.

Its done.

Thanks to @Javich

Comment: Works. Filter for "Backspace" instead of "Delete" is even quicker since the list is shorter.

Comment: if the incorrect behaviour continues after applying changes, try closing the files you were editing and open them again.