# Ubuntu Eclipse : Backspace key started working like Delete key

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, key, text-editor

I am working on Eclipse, backspace key works all fine but suddenly it's started working like delete key (When press backspace we expect to delete backward characters but its deleting front characters).

Is their its an Eclipse functionality? or bug I am not sure. If functionality then let know how to make it correct.

It's really a weird type of issue. Not able to work smoothly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backspace key is reverted in Eclipse Mars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823185/backspace-key-is-reverted-in-eclipse-mars)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Got solved:

Go to "Window -> Preferences". Then inside the tree navigate to "General -> Keys".

In the right side of the window, type "Delete" where it says "type filter text".

Find the  **COMMAND**: `Delete`, **BINDING**: `Backspace` and click on `UnBind Command` button at the bottom. Click `Apply`, then `OK`.

Its done.

Thanks to @Javich

Comment: Nice solution.  The question that comes to mind, though, is how did this happen in the first place?

Comment: then ,why this happens?

Comment: I know this is late, but it just happened to me on Windows 10! Mid way though typing, backspace starts deleting! The solution works, but I do wonder how this happened.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a Eclipse problem. It happened to me on Eclipse Luna Windows 8 (Java 8). I also ran that same Eclipse on Ubuntu and it didn't happen.

Long story short, here is a workaround:
Go to  "Window -> Preferences".
Then  inside the tree navigate to
"General -> Keys".

In the right side of the window, type "Delete" where it says "type filter text".
Find the "Delete Previous" binding and click on it.
Click on the " < " button in right of the "Binding" text area and select "Backspace".
Click "Apply", then "OK".

Done. You are good to go.

[Fix Example on Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXstQ.png)

Comment: Thank you Javich. I already tried that but, unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `"Window -> Preferences >> General -> Keys"`.
type "Delete" where it says "type filter text".

Find the COMMAND: Delete, BINDING: Backspace and click on UnBind Command button at the bottom. Click Apply, then OK.